# Bunch of Records displaying in Custom View android but Very Time Consuming

Tags: android, sqlite, android-tablelayout

I am developing Android Application which is Syncing data from Server.

Server has thousands of records that i have stored in `SQLite Database.`

But now i am displaying records in custom `TableView` Successfully, but its very time consuming and i got black screen for 10 to 20 seconds.

**My code is:**

```
/**** FILL ALL DATA OF PRODUCT WHICH IS AVAILABLE IN THIS COMPANY ****/
        dbHelper.open();

        productCursor = dbHelper.getProduct(companyid, isDistributor);

        if(productCursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            productTable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            (view.findViewById(R.id.productIfNoAvailable)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            TableRow row= null;

            com.salesman.library.ImageLoader mImageLoader = new com.salesman.library.ImageLoader(context);
            ImageView prodImage;
            TextView prodName;
            EditText prodRate = null;
            EditText prodQty = null;
            EditText prodDisc = null;

            /** For every time add new row in Table Layout **/
            productTable.removeAllViews();

            rowid = 0;
            int catid = 0;

            while (productCursor.moveToNext()) {
                final View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_product_view, null);

                row = new TableRow(context);
                catid = productCursor.getInt(productCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID));

                int concatid = Integer.parseInt(catid+""+rowid++);

                row.setId(concatid);

                row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                double productRateValue;
                double productDiscountValue;

                productRateValue = productCursor.getDouble(productCursor.getColumnIndex("rate"));
                productDiscountValue = productCursor.getDouble(productCursor.getColumnIndex("discount"));

                /*** Image ***/
                prodImage = (ImageView) childView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
                String path = productCursor.getString(productCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PRODUCT_IMAGES));
                mImageLoader.DisplayImage(path, prodImage);

                prodName = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
                prodName.setText(productCursor.getString(productCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PRODUCT_NAME)));

                prodQty = (EditText) childView.findViewById(R.id.productQuantityValue);
                prodQty.setText("");

                prodRate = (EditText) childView.findViewById(R.id.productRateValue);
                prodRate.setText(String.valueOf(productRateValue));

                prodDisc = (EditText) childView.findViewById(R.id.productDiscountValue);
                prodDisc.setText(String.valueOf(productDiscountValue));

                prodRate.setFocusable(isRateEditable);
                prodRate.setEnabled(isRateEditable);

                prodDisc.setFocusable(isDiscountEditable);
                prodDisc.setEnabled(isDiscountEditable);


                row.addView(childView);
                productTable.addView(row);

                if(productSharedPref.getBoolean("saved", false))
                {
                    View rowView = productTable.findViewById(concatid);
                    String prodRatePrefValue    = productSharedPref.getString("rate"+concatid, "");
                    String prodQtyPrefValue     = productSharedPref.getString("qty"+concatid, "");
                    String prodDiscPrefValue    = productSharedPref.getString("discount"+concatid, "");

                    if(!prodQtyPrefValue.equals("") || prodQtyPrefValue != null)
                        ((EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.productQuantityValue)).setText(prodQtyPrefValue);

                    if(!prodRatePrefValue.equals(""))
                        ((EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.productRateValue)).setText(prodRatePrefValue);

                    if(!prodDiscPrefValue.equals(""))
                        ((EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.productDiscountValue)).setText(prodDiscPrefValue);
                }
            }
```

How to reduce this time.

Please Help.

Comment: You can use `CursorLoader`

Comment: 1000's of record. Maybe instead of getting all of them at once, get limited number of them at a time. Then show it to the user. If user scroll through all those rows, then load another set of the rows. Go on like that. I donno how to do it but seems like something which you may think of.

Comment: Yes, Thanks but how to perform this.

Comment: Sorry but most of your approach is wrong. You should be using a ListView that dynamically re-uses views. This way you're creating thousands of views to keep in memory for no good reason, slowing down your process and probably will crash the app on older devices with OutOfMemory. Find on Google a good tutorial on ListView, ListAdapter and CursorAdapter. That's what you have to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async task.....what it does is loads a few items and displays the screen...and then it will keep updating the list with the new items,when they are processed

Comment: How to use `AsyncTask` in Fragment

Comment: there are already question posted on the question you just asked...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359649/update-listfragment-after-asynctask

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152767/updating-a-listfragment-based-on-async-task-result